# Best performance for find objects in entities and load entities, Foreach or where with LinQ ON C#?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, load

I need to relate a few entities. Right now the code is loaded the first entity and then is iterated with a foreach loop and search on each record if the current row match with the property of the record of the other entity.
Something like:

```
  foreach (Entity1 e1 in entity1List)
  {
   foreach (Entity2 e2 in entity2List)
   {
    if (e2.Id == e1.Id)
    {
     //Do something
    }
   }
  }
```

But the entities have a lot of records and the performance is not being good.
I want to improve the speed trying to use linQ for search the record.

var list = entity2List.Where(e2 => entity1.Any(e1 => e1.Id == e2.Id));

```
  foreach (Entity2 e2 in list )
  {
  //Do something
  }
```

But I don't know if this is really helping for the performance. Also I would like to know the best model for load the entities in this case. Some advises or links for read or tools for compare times of execution, please.

I'm using a lot of joins for the loaders of each entity, but are separate because, testing with other cases the rows are a lot and the time from execute the query on  the DB was too much, so now the entities are independent and I want to create the dependency by code.

Comment: You could always profile both and find out. (Hint: loading fewer records than greater records will always result in a net gain).

Comment: Any reason you're not using a join?

Comment: And switch from a List<T> to a HashSet<T> or use a Dictionary. Moving from list to Hash/Dict will speed all lookups substantially

Comment: I'm using a lot of joins for the loaders of each entity, but are separate because, testing with other cases the rows are a lot and the time from excute the query on  the DB was too much, so now the entities are independent and I want to create the dependency by code

Comment: Are these really lists with materialized entities, or you mean database tables?

Comment: Lists with materialized entities

Answer (score 1):

If both entity sets are really lists, using LINQ `Where` will not give you a performance improvement because it's equivalent of your current linear search algorithm with O(M * N) time complexity.

However you can get much better O(M + N) time complexity algorithm (thus performance) by using LINQ [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which internally uses quite efficient hash based lookup to correlate the two sequences:

```
var list = from e1 in entity1List
           join e2 in entity2List on e1.Id equals e2.Id into e2Group
           select new { e1, e2Group };

foreach (var item in list)
{
    var e1 = item.e1;
    foreach (var e2 in item.e2Group)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

If you don't need nested `foreach` loop for your processing, you could use [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which is even slightly more efficient:

```
var list = from e1 in entity1List
           join e2 in entity2List on e1.Id equals e2.Id
           select new { e1, e2 };

foreach (var item in list)
{
    var e1 = item.e1;
    var e2 = item.e2;
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks I compared the time of my methods with dotTrace and is now better

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidL says, you might want to test both solutions and see what happens. Another option is to make a hash with the first collection and then search there by key. It should affect the performance.

Example:

```
var e1ById = entity1List.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key); //you can skip the GroupBy if you know Id is a unique key)

foreach(var e2 in entity2List.Where(x => e1ById.ContainsKey(e2.Id)))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Or maybe use a list to store keys:

```
var keys = entity1List.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().ToList();

foreach(var e2 in entity2List.Where(x => keys.Contains(x.Id))
{
    //Do something
}
```

In any case, the performance depends on the initial collection length so try the different solutions and take note of the times.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if performance is your main concern, you are usually better writing your own optimized algorithm. LINQ will certainly be slower than your optimal algorithm because of overheads. However, LINQ is elegant and very useful for code maintainability. so, choice is yours!

In this particular case, you can use ***Intersect()*** method, which is more efficient and simpler than your current implementation.

```
foreach (var element in entity1List.Intersect(entity2List))
{
// Do something
}
```